# Shortening simple IF formula in Xcel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What is a simple way to expand the following formula so it applies to rows 2-20 of my spreadsheet:

```
=SUM(IF(B2=1,M2),IF(B3=1,M3),IF(B4=1,M4))
```

Comment: This formula does not sum any values.  It just returns the value of M2, M3 OR M4, based on which is true FIRST (b2, b3 or b4=1).  What is it that the formula is supposed to do?

Comment: It is supposed to add up the values in cell M for the rows in which the text in cell B is '1'.  It works on my spreadsheet....but would take a long time to type out for many rows of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula will add up the rows in column M, if the same row column B = 1.

```
SUMIF(B2:B20,1,M2:M20)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
= SUMPRODUCT( ( B2:B20 = 1 ) * M2:M20 )
```

or

```
= SUMIF(B2:B20, 1, M2:M20)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDEX($M$2:$M$20,MATCH(1,$B$2:$B$20,0))
```